# UIStackView show/hide animation is not working properly

Tags: ios, uikit, uistackview

I'm using UIStackView and it contains 3 UIView instances, which has fixed height

I'm trying to hide these subviews by clicking button

first and second view show/hide well with proper animation

but last view doesn't animate

[image]

[image]

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var flag: Bool = true
    @IBOutlet weak var targetView: UIView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        flag = !flag
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.targetView.isHidden = !self.flag
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the way stack views change their frames when hiding an arranged subview.

Easiest way to see what's happening:

- set your Green view to `Alpha: 0.5`
- toggle `.isHidden` on the Blue view

You'll see that the 50% translucent Green view "slides up over" the Blue view... the Blue view does not "shrink in height" during the animation.

To solve your **specific** issue, set `Clips To Bounds` to `true` on your stack view. Now, when you toggle `.isHidden` on your Green view, the animation will look correct.

That will not change the "slide over" appearance if you have translucent views, but that's a different issue.

As a side note, you can simplify your code and get rid of the `flag` like this:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        // not needed
        //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.targetView.isHidden.toggle()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code from:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.targetView.isHidden = !self.flag
    }
```

to:

```
    self.targetView.isHidden = !self.flag

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Looks like you animate before change.

Comment: it doesn't work. if I hide second view, it animates properly. the problem is last view

Comment: check if StackView have height constraint set.